# php $_FILE doesn't work

Tags: raspbian, php

I followed all the steps from tutorial [WikiHow - Guide to install PHP](http://www.wikihow.com/Discussion%3aMake-a-Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server)

I can execute normal php commands, but **can't upload files using $_FILE** command.It always gives me error.

My File uploading script is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="file_uploader.php" method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my **file_uploader.php** file code is

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if(1)
  {
    print_r($_FILES);

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

In above code , you can see i set condition to always true,so it doesn't give any error but also it doesn't upload file.

the output of it is

```
Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => college.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/php4aaDd6 [error] => 0 [size] => 113731 ) ) /tmpUpload: college.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 111.0654296875 kB
Stored in: /tmp/php4aaDd6 Stored in: upload/college.jpg
```

and inspire of this output , I can't find file at that location.

My php.ini file configuration can be seen [php.ini - Pastebin URL](http://pastebin.com/z5fznYqC)

Comment: try changing the first if-statement to just `if ( true )`. Alternatively just do a `print_r($_FILES);` to see if any file has been uploaded.

Comment: the array gives following description ,  [name] => Icon.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpR2tspv [error] => 0 [size] => 393576 ) , that means file is received but still I can't find it in upload folder.... @Gerben

Comment: The example code you are using only accepts 20kb files. Icon.png is 394kb. That is why it is not working! Just change the 20000 to some larger number.

Comment: @Gerben , I have edited my question , it contains my uploading logic.

Comment: Have you changed the permissions of the `upload` folder? Webserver run under a different username, so by default, they can't write to a folder you (as user `pi`) have created. Just run `chmod a+x upload`

Comment: I tried chmod command to give permissions and also tested by touch command , and touch command works fine. Yet I am facing the problem. @Gerben

Comment: Does the file exist in the `/tmp` folder?

Comment: No it doesn't exist in /tmp folder.